# From hourly data, get daily nsmallest values for each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df with n columns, with hourly data (date_i X1_i X2_i ... Xn_i).
For each day, I want to get the nsmallest values for each column. But i cannot find a way without looping over the columns.
It is easy with the smallest value as df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).min() seems to do the trick, but when I try the nsmallest method, i get the following error message :
 "Cannot access callable attribute 'nsmallest' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method".
I tried to use nsmallest with the 'apply' method but was asked to specify columns...
If someone has an idea, it would be very helpful
Thanks
PS : sorry for the formatting, this is my first post ever

Edit : some illustrations
what my data looks like :

```
                             0             1     ...          9678          9679
2022-01-08 00:00:00  18472.232746  28934.878033  ...  20668.503228  22079.457224
2022-01-08 01:00:00  19546.101746  30239.880033  ...  21789.779228  23330.190224
2022-01-08 02:00:00  22031.448746  33016.048033  ...  24278.199228  25990.503224
2022-01-08 03:00:00  24089.368644  36134.608919  ...  26327.332591  28089.134306
2022-01-08 04:00:00  24640.942644  36818.412919  ...  26894.204591  28736.705306
2022-01-08 05:00:00  23329.700644  35639.693919  ...  25555.199591  27379.323306
2022-01-08 06:00:00  20990.043644  33329.805919  ...  23137.500591  24917.126306
2022-01-08 07:00:00  18314.599644  30347.799919  ...  20167.500591  22022.524306
2022-01-08 08:00:00  17628.482226  31301.113041  ...  21665.296600  24202.625832
2022-01-08 09:00:00  15743.339226  29588.354041  ...  19912.297600  22341.947832
2022-01-08 10:00:00  15498.405226  29453.561041  ...  19799.009600  22131.170832
2022-01-08 11:00:00  14950.121226  28767.791041  ...  19328.678600  21507.167832
2022-01-08 12:00:00  13925.869226  27530.472041  ...  18404.139600  20460.316832
2022-01-08 13:00:00  17502.122226  30922.783041  ...  21990.380600  24008.382832
2022-01-08 14:00:00  19159.511385  34275.005187  ...  23961.590286  26460.214883
2022-01-08 15:00:00  20583.356385  35751.662187  ...  25315.380286  27793.800883
2022-01-08 16:00:00  20443.423385  35925.362187  ...  25184.576286  27672.536883
2022-01-08 17:00:00  15825.211385  31604.614187  ...  20646.669286  23145.311883
2022-01-08 18:00:00  11902.354052  28786.559805  ...  16028.363856  19313.677750
2022-01-08 19:00:00  13483.710052  30631.806805  ...  17635.338856  20948.556750
2022-01-08 20:00:00  16084.773323  33944.862396  ...  20627.810852  22763.962851
2022-01-08 21:00:00  18340.833323  36435.799396  ...  22920.037852  25240.320851
2022-01-08 22:00:00  15110.698323  33159.222396  ...  19794.355852  22102.416851
2022-01-08 23:00:00  15663.400323  33741.501396  ...  20180.693852  22605.909851
2022-01-09 00:00:00  19500.930751  39058.431760  ...  24127.257756  26919.289816
2022-01-09 01:00:00  20562.985751  40330.807760  ...  25123.488756  28051.573816
2022-01-09 02:00:00  23408.547751  43253.635760  ...  27840.447756  30960.372816
2022-01-09 03:00:00  25975.071191  45523.722743  ...  30274.316013  32276.174330
2022-01-09 04:00:00  27180.858191  46586.959743  ...  31348.131013  33414.631330
2022-01-09 05:00:00  26383.511191  45793.920743  ...  30598.931013  32605.280330
                          ...           ...  ...           ...           ...
```

What i get with the min function :

```
2022-01-08  11902.354052  27530.472041  ...  16028.363856  19313.677750
2022-01-09  14491.281907  30293.870235  ...  16766.428013  21386.135041
...
```

What i would like to have, for example with nsmallest(2)

```
2022-01-08  11902.354052  27530.472041  ...  16028.363856  19313.677750
            13483.710052  28767.791041  ...  17635.338856  20460.316832
2022-01-09  14491.281907  30293.870235  ...  16766.428013  21386.135041
            14721.392907  30722.928235  ...  17130.594013  21732.426041
...
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data that you're working with, as well as the expected output from your sample? This will help people understand what your data looks like and know if their solution is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Group by days and get the 2 smallest values as a list and explode all columns (`pandas>=1.3.0`)

```
get_2smallest = lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).tolist()
out = df.resample('D').apply(get_2smallest).explode(df.columns.tolist())
print(out)

# Output
                       0             1          9678          9679
2022-01-08  11902.354052  27530.472041  16028.363856   19313.67775
2022-01-08  13483.710052  28767.791041  17635.338856  20460.316832
2022-01-09  19500.930751   39058.43176  24127.257756  26919.289816
2022-01-09  20562.985751   40330.80776  25123.488756  28051.573816
```

**Update**

Another version, maybe faster:

```
out = df.set_index(df.index.date).stack().rename_axis(['Date', 'Col']) \
        .rename('Val').sort_values().groupby(level=[0, 1]).head(2) \
        .sort_index().reset_index().assign(Idx=lambda x: x.index % 2) \
        .pivot(index=['Date', 'Idx'], columns='Col', values='Val') \
        .droplevel('Idx').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That one-liner works. 
However the execution time is not significantly lower than the loop over the columns. Since the data is quite big, it's probably impossible to make it quicker